# Windows 10 black screen during the installation

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, bootable-media

I have a HP Probook 6570b laptop running Ubuntu and I am trying to install Windows 10 on it now. I have downloaded the ISO from Microsoft's website and created a bootable usb flashdrive to install it.

The laptop recognises the flashdrive and lets me boot from it, but I only get a black screen (without any cursor) after booting.

I have already tried the Win+P key combination to try trick the windows mirroring settings (fail). All other suggestions I found require access to a working Windows installation (e.g. update or disabling drivers, etc).

The other thing I was told to check was BIOS settings, but unfortunately HP has password protected it from the factory, and the only way to reset the password is, you guessed it, using Windows. ‍♂️

Is there anything else I could do to get Windows to install on this laptop?

Comment: *check was BIOS settings, but unfortunately HP has password protected it from the factory* - That is highly irregular. What is displayed when you try to enter BIOS setup by pressing F10 at boot?

Comment: It asks me for a password. I enter anything random 3 times and then it locks up the system and requires a reboot. I agree it’s quite irregular and very irritating

Comment: You should contact HP about this. The BIOS password is supposed to be set by the owner, not at the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried this, I found that it was impossible to burn to a USB drive that would boot a Windows 10 image using Ubuntu. The system will attempt to boot, but nothing will happen. This was also on a BIOS (not UEFI) machine. Solutions:

- Burn a DVD (instead of a USB) with the Windows 10 image. Note that not all Windows 10 ISOs will fit on a 4.7 GB DVD anymore, so an older image may be needed.
- Get Rufus, a Windows image burning program, running on Linux using an emulator like Wine or a Windows 10 virtual machine. Or run it on an older version of Windows if you have historical Windows installation media lying around.
- Get WoeUSB, an unmaintained Linux program, working. IIRC, I had to install Fedora to install it and was only able to get it working after a lot of effort messing with command-line arguments because it's buggy.